# How to get certain string from custom ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java

I want to read the content of a file and store each line of the file into a custom ArrayList. The content of the file is like:

```
1 Marwan male 22

2 Julia female 18

3 John male 19

4 William male 21

5 Mia female 20
```

This is what I did so far:

```
public static ArrayList<st> myArray = new ArrayList<st>();
public static st s = new st();

s.id=lineScan.next();
s.name=lineScan.next();
s.gender=lineScan.next();
s.age=lineScan.nextInt();
myArray.add(s);

class st {
    String id;
    String name; 
    String gender; 
    int age; 
}
```

I want to get the s.name string for every time the gender is male and print them out together, and do the same with the female gender, but I don't know how to get certain strings from the array list.

Comment: Your question is how to get the values from the arraylist? Use [`ArrayList#get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)). For example `System.out.print(myArray.get(0).name);`.

Comment: I tried it and it prints out only the last name in the list

Comment: so the printing code that you have tried.  Also why is `st` static?

Comment: It prints out the name of the first student in the list. Obviously I can't solve your problem, because you haven't explained exactly what the problem is. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Stream.of(IOUtil.readLines(new File(filePath)))
    .map(line -> Splitter.with(" ").trim(true).splitToArray(line))
    .groupBy(a -> a[1], a -> a[0], (a, b) -> a + ", " + b)
    .forEach(N::println);
// output:
// female=Julia, Mia
// male=Marwan, John, William
```

Declaration： I'm the developer of abacus-common.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
 for(st s: myArray){
         System.out.println(s.gender+" "+s.name)}
```